# Как не дублировать отправку письма при одновременных http запросах

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, http

Сейчас есть текущая реализация такая:
приходят N  HTTP запросов, прямо друг за другом (конкретно не больше 5). В обработчике HTTP запроса отправляется email. Соответственно сейчас email отправляется N раз — по количеству запросов.

Необходимо исправить — чтобы email отправлялся только 1 раз — не смотря на N запросов
Привожу тестовую реализацию (реальный код не могу прислать). При первом запросе статический флаг устанавливается в true – таким же он останется и при последующих запросах.  Тут же запускается таймер. Через безопасный интервал флаг сбрасывается. Интервал — это примерное время, через которое пользователь опять инициирует действия, вызвавшее отправку email

Я бы хотел избавиться от таймера и флага — нужно как-то отслеживать сколько запросов и каких пришло. Как это сделать и можно ли?

Ещё вариант который вижу — хранить в БД признак, но не хотелось бы этого делать.

```
public class HomeService
{
    private static bool _isMessageSent = false;
    private Timer aTimer;

    public void SetIsMessageSent()
    {
        SetTimer();
        _isMessageSent = true;
    }

    private static void ResetIsMessageSent()
    {
        _isMessageSent = false;
    }

    private void SetTimer()
    {
        aTimer = new Timer(20000);
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.AutoReset = false;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        ResetIsMessageSent();
        aTimer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}",
                          e.SignalTime);
    }
}



public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly HomeService _homeService;
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _homeService = new HomeService();
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _homeService.SetIsMessageSent();
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Переделайте архитектуру: вместо того, чтобы отправлять письмо - просто ставьте событие отправки в некоторую очередь, уже из которой постепенно отправляются письма. Очередь запоминает какие письма отправлялись, поэтому при попытке поставить в очередь слишком быстро несколько одинаковых событий - они молча будут игнорироваться и не вставляться. Вероятно, проще всего будет думать об этой очереди как о таблице в базе данных, но возможны и иные варианты: не хотите базу - значит добровольно согласились что если сервис грохнется, то часть писем не уйдёт или могут быть повторы. Чего больше не хочется?

Comment: Вы говорите о брокере типа RabbitMQ? Он есть на проекте, он как раз стоит в середине цепочки отправки

Comment: Хорошо, что у вас есть брокер, но я подумал, что вы не знаете о таких сложных вещах, т.к. и признак в базе боитесь сделать. Вообще, rabbit - это стрельба из атомной пушки по воробьям. Вы можете сделать `List<EmailEvent>` статическим объектом и добавлять туда события и убирать оттуда события и проверять, стоит ли вставлять или ещё не прошло пять минут с момента последнего события. Вам этот вариант наверняка не понравится, я почему-то часто вижу эту непоследовательность в SPR: то булеву переменную неохота, то рэббитом шахарнут, то не согласны на компромисс. Всё не нравится. Выберите сами.

Comment: Сформулируйте чётче что вы хотите в итоге. Вот пришло одновременно N запросов - что вы хотите, чтобы происходило при этом и в каком порядке? Если запросы разные - ну есть `ConcurrentBag`, есть `ConcurrentDictionary`, есть `ConcurrentQueue`, плюс есть `SemaphoreSlim`, всё решаемо, но нужно определиться, что именно вы хотите получить, какое поведение.